# eZ Publish 6 (eZPlatform) connection issue

Tags: php, symfony, ezpublish, ezplatform

I have a problem after installation with eZPublish 6. When I try to connect on `localhost:8000/app.php/ez` with username admin with the default password (publish), this error occures :

[image]

#### Logs

> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to
>   listener
>   "eZ\Bundle\EzPublishCoreBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand".
>   [] []
>
> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/var/www/html/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":55,"level":28928}
>   []
>
> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate"
>   to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate".
>   [] []
>
> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate"
>   to listener
>   "FOS\HttpCacheBundle\EventListener\InvalidationSubscriber::onConsoleTerminate".
>   [] []
>
> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate"
>   to listener
>   "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
>
> [2016-02-09 09:43:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate"
>   to listener
>   "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []

I also tried to change the encrypted password in the database, and nothing changes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. It was caused by `SELinux` on Fedora 23.

My goal was to access to the ezPlatform's User Interface via port `80`. 
I created vhosts, you can find a lot of examples on the web.

Here's one solution:

First, remove the app.php in the URL, as Patrizio Bekerle said.
 Then, remove :8000 from the URL - here I had an Access Denied to the webpage.

To correct this access problem, just follow the instructions here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31907528/5655273

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your server with something like `php app/console server:run`?

Try opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/ez or remove the `/app.php` from your url. Having the php in the url triggers that error.

Hope it helps.